# Page.LoadControl throwing "Access Denied" for new controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-permissions

I am in deep trouble.

Previously I was developing my website on Windows7 using VS2012. I recently Installed win8 and migrated all my projects to win8 and then setup vs2012 and continued my development. Everything was working fine. I have loads of ascx controls that I load in my website dynamically using the Page.LoadControl method. Existing controls loading perfect. But when I am creating new controls, they are not loading. The method fails and throws "Access Denied" I am a bit puzzled. What is wrong that the new files dont have permissions?

Can any body guide me how to solve this permission issue?

**Update**: I wonder even the File.Exists(path) is unable to find the file. I printed the path and when I access that path, i can see that file.

Thanks

Comment: Can you check the security tab on the physical files? Compare a one you created recently with an old one and see if there is a difference. The folder that holds your ascx file may have had its permissions changed when you migrated your files.

Comment: @AlaaMasoud, Thanks dude. Actually I was checking the permissions with my other guy and found IIS_IUSRS and IUSR was missing from the Group/User. I see they coming up with the old files but not with the new ones. Thanks for your help, much appreciated.